# Sharing memory between managed and unmanaged code with P/Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I created a C wrapper for a C++ library and I'm calling this C wrapper from my C# managed code. The problem I am facing is that this library involves thousands of iterations and long runtimes. Obviously I need a way to communicate with the C# program and update the status of the processing the C/C++ library is doing.

The straighforward approach would be returning after a fixed number of iterations, updating the status and calling the C/C++ wrapper again. But the processing depends on some C++ STL based data structures that are updated after each iteration. I don't need these data structures on my managed code, but obviously they must be maintained in memory for all the iterations.

So I cannot return from the C/C++ wrapper until the processing is completed, otherwise the C++ structures would be deallocated...

I am thinking the best approach would be sharing some variables between managed and unmanaged code, and read the status of the processing every N iterations. But this leads to another problem: how can I synchronize access to this memory?

Comment: Why would the data-structures be de-allocated when the wrapper returns?

Comment: Because they are allocated by the called function. Using global variables or unreleased dynamic memory seems a dirty and unstable solution. Can I be sure that this dynamic memory or global variables won't be cleaned up after a call to the wrapper? What if the DLL is unloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a C# delegate as callback in your C++ code. In that way you do not have to return from your wrapper, but your wrapper could call the C# delegate via callback and could then continue processing. Your delegate can also contain some parameters which you can use to interchange data between your C# and your C++ layer.

See a more complete description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0.aspx).

The main trick here is to use the method [GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at4fb09f.aspx) which lets you create a C++ function pointer out of your C# delegate so that you can call your C# code from your C++ layer.

Comment: It doesn't require a trick, the pinvoke marshaller already uses GFPFD to marshal a delegate.

Comment: Thanks. Since I am a beginner with P/Invoke I had no idea about this feature. It seems the best approach to implement the status updates.

Comment: @Hans Passant. Thanks, good to know, last time I used it only within a C++/CLI wrapper.